# Make Android App Compatible for all 6735 Android Devices

Tags: android, mobile-devices

Google Play support 6735 Android Devices that info i got from Google Play Developer Account, I have created an Android App which support 4555 Android Devices, and not supporting rest of the Android devices, i don't know why this happen infect i have given all kind of supporting permission in Android Manifest that is mention below:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="720" />


 <compatible-screens>

    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>   

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Can anyone help to make my android app which supports all 6735 Android Devices

Comment: @Ker p pag 
Every Android Device has their own Screen dimension so i given a permission to my app to support all kind of screen dimension

Comment: actually my app is working fine on almost all android devices, but some of the devices showing my app is not compatible for that device like Samsung Galaxy Note 3, it is working fine in Samsung Galaxy Note 2, this is my issue.

Comment: 1) there is no official api 21, highest **targetSdkVersion** you can set is 19. 2) you will not succeed since you set minsdk to 14, there are still many devices on api 9/10.

Comment: I think you are using old SDK till now just upgrade you SDK there Android updated there API Level 20 and 21 as well,


Actually in my app i used Fragment which required at least API Level 11, that's why i used the API Level more than 11, anyway thanks for your comment actually i resolved my problem just i removed all the tags except <uses-sdk .../> and its solved my problem now my app is compatible with Galaxy Note 3. Thanks.....

Comment: The latest released **API** is still **19**. L preview is set to 20, the same as for Wear. You shouldn't invent numbers on your own, you're more than likely to end up in more trouble than what you think you'll gain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete basically everything you've posted except for `<uses-sdk .../>`. You should not need to define these by default, and doing so will only *reduce* the number of compatible devices. Enable them only as you find that they are actually needed by the app.

Take a look at the documentation for [supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) and [compatible-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) to see how these are supposed to be used.

Comment: I done as you suggest and my problem got solved, Thanks Buddy

Comment: hello please help me. what did you change?   @AjayPrasad

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Your app is using min sdk version 14 which is android 4.0

15 % devices still run on android 2.2 and 2.3 which are unsupported by your app

Click here for more info about android version https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

You need to make your project compatible with atleast android 2.3 to support about 6000 devices from 6735 total devices.

You typically want to target as many users as possible , so you would ideally want to support everyone with minimum sdk 1. how ever that has some disadvantages such as lack of features, programming support and most people dont use devices below android 2.2 anyway

Your choice of minimum sdk is a trade off between the distribution of users you want to target and the features that your application will need

Note that all devices cannot be supported due to some features of your app being unavailable in some phone, although i can't comment on why it is not supported on note 3 with the information given here

Comment: Actually in my app i used Fragment which required at least API Level 11, that's why i used the API Level more than 11, anyway thanks for your comment actually i resolved my problem just i removed all the tags except <uses-sdk .../> and its solved my problem now my app is compatible with Galaxy Note 3. Thanks.....

Comment: How many devices does it support now ( out of 6735) . You can't support all devices as fragments feature which you are using is not available on devices below API level 11

Comment: Ya its true, now my app support about 5120 Devices.

Answer (score -1):

If you want that your Android Application support all devices screen size try this viedo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsPzDf_JVZs

Comment: Thanks for you answer but link only answers are not encouraged in SO, as they can expire, rather copy the relevant code or explanation here.

Comment: Video is not available